# Set focus on a specific element in Durandal single page application

Tags: set, focus, durandal

How do you set focus on a specific element in a durandal single page application?

Comment: The same way you do in a non-Durandal application. Odd question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should be able to use addBindingHandler for this specific purpose.](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html)

As an example :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hasFocus = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).focus(function() {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(true);
        });
        $(element).blur(function() {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(false);
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.unwrap(value))
            element.focus();
        else
            element.blur();
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this same thing... but I didn't work... I cant get the specific element focused

Comment: To get this working in some versions of IE, you may find that you need to wrap element.focus() within a setTimeout.